# Metadata API - deploy custom field created in a managed package object

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, ant-script

I have created a custom field on a managed package object. I know I can retrieve the field or the object using the metadata API

```
<types>
  <members>TheManagedPackageCustomObject__c.MyCustomField__c</members>
  <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
<!-OR-->
<types>
  <members>TheManagedPackageCustomObject__c</members>
  <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

I don't think I will be able to deploy the whole object that's for sure. So I was wondering if it's possible to deploy this custom field I created in a managed package via ant script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We regularly use Ant-based [sf:deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm) to pull and push individual non-namespaced fields on standard objects and custom objects including custom objects that are part of a managed package.

We also push in namespaced fields that are part of a managed package where, for example, picklist values need to be changed. But I assume any part of the field that is locked down in the managed package will not be changeable this way.

Comment: Do you deploy what's in the "Referenced Packages" or you add manually the managed package object in the package.xml?

Comment: @brovasi I've only ever manually added. Object and field name will both have the managed package namespace prefix when the field comes from a managed package.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the above method, you can deploy a Custom field that you have created in a managed package object using ZuppIO.

We call this 'Not upgradeable components' and there are much more than just the Custom field.

To deliver Custom field you need to setup the step with Custom field, and this step includes the copying of the fields within the namespace of your package. Please refer to the [link](https://zupp.io/mass-post-install-updates?position=main) of Website.
This is not a problem when you have a small number of clients (subscribers), but once this number grows - this becomes a nightmare to do every next package upgrade.
The idea is to always have the TSO environment with everything set up as desired, and use this org as a Source in ZuppIO so ZuppIO can take the desired not upgradeable components from TSO and deliver to some or to all your subscriber's orgs (targets).

Disclaimer: I work for SuccessCraft, the maker of ZuppIO. So, I am biased but can give you names of competing products you can test to form your own opinions.

Comment: Still not wild about you continuing to push your product after the spam campaign and without otherwise contributing to the community here.